# MySql Workbench error 1064, how can i solve this error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i'm trying to do a forward engineering and at the end it gaves me this error

> "ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS Amministrazione' at line 1"

SQL Code: `DROP USER IF EXISTS Amministrazione`

This is the code:

```
SET SQL_MODE = '';

DROP USER IF EXISTS Amministrazione;
SET SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
CREATE USER 'Amministrazione' IDENTIFIED BY 'amministrazione';

GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `GestioneCorsiDiLingue`.`Generare report Insegnante Mensile` TO 'Amministrazione';
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `GestioneCorsiDiLingue`.`Elimina Corso` TO 'Amministrazione';
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `GestioneCorsiDiLingue`.`Aggiunta Insegnante` TO 'Amministrazione';
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `GestioneCorsiDiLingue`.`Elimina Insegnante` TO 'Amministrazione';
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `GestioneCorsiDiLingue`.`Creazione corso` TO 'Amministrazione';
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `GestioneCorsiDiLingue`.`Assegnazione insegnanti a corso` TO 'Amministrazione';
```

if you can please help me it would be great because i can't really figure out what's the problem, if you need further details just ask me!

Comment: don't use spaces in colimns tables procedures or functins, this is will cause problems in the log run

Comment: besides which mysql version do you have

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to solve this error is to upgrade to MySQL 5.7 (or later).

The "`IF EXISTS`" option for `DROP USER` was not supported before MySQL 5.7. If your MySQL Server is an earlier version, that syntax will return error 1064.

You can use `DROP USER` in older versions of MySQL, but not `DROP USER IF EXISTS`.

I'm talking about the version of MySQL Server, regardless of the version of the client like MySQL Workbench. The SQL syntax you can use is that which is supported by the server.

You can verify your MySQL Server version:

```
SELECT @@version;
```

P.S. MySQL 5.6 reached its [end-of-life as of 2021-02-05](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql) (that is, yesterday as I post this). So you should upgrade anyway.